# Update database php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `test` = '$unicornID' where id='$_SESSION[user_id]' ")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Now, when user clicks 'add to favorite'-button this line of code updates my database but also deletes all the old data from column `test`. What command should so that the old data is not deleted?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may be looking for is an "INSERT" sql query.

It would be something along the lines of;

```
"INSERT * INTO users WHERE test='$unicornID' and id='$_SESION['user_id']'";
```

Let me know how it goes. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Another tip.
Use PDO with prepared statements:

```
$pdo = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', HOST, DATABASE), USER, PASSWORD);
```

And to insert something:

```
$params = array(':unicornID' => $unicornID, ':id' => $_SESSION['user_id']);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT * INTO users WHERE test=:unicornID and id=:id");
$stmt->execute($params);
```

The old mysql(_query) commands are old and very vulnerable, PDO isn't as vulnerable.
The advantage of prepared statements are mainly that you can't inject via your variables some sql code.

Hope you understood my and my code

Answer (score 0):

"Update" means that the old data row is changed; if you want to keep it, you have to insert a new one. In this case I think that you should copy the row (which may be done using "insert... select...") and then update the newly inserted line.